# Mavericks Style Tagging

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstokenfield, nstokenfieldcell

I'm quite new to cocoa and I'm trying to find out how I can create something similar to the new tagging UI in Mavericks:

[image]

I assume, I'll have to overwrite NSTokenFieldCell to get the coloured dots or an icon on the tags. But how does this popup list work?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you'll have to roll your own. Almost all of the drawing taking place in `NSTokenFieldCell` is private, so adding any kind of ornamental elements would have to be done by you. If I remember correctly, `NSTokenFieldCell` uses an `NSTokenTextView` instead of the window's standard field editor. I'm not sure what's different about it, but I think it's mostly to deal with the specialized nature of "tokenizing" attributed strings. I think they just use `NSAttachmentCell` objects for the graphical tokens, and when the cell receives a `-mouseDown:` event, they show the menu.

The menu part would actually be pretty easy because you can add images to menu items like so:

```
NSMenuItem *redItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Red"
                                                 action:@selector(chooseColorMenuItem:)
                                          keyEquivalent:@""];

// You could add an image from your app's Resources folder:
NSImage *redSwatchImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"red-menu-item-swatch"];

// ----- or -----

// You could dynamically draw a color swatch and use that as its image:
NSImage *redSwatchImage = [NSImage imageWithSize:NSMakeSize(16.0, 16.0) 
                                         flipped:NO 
                                  drawingHandler:^BOOL(NSRect dstRect) {

    NSRect pathRect = NSInsetRect(dstRect, 0.5, 0.5); // Aligns border to integral values
    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:pathRect];
    NSColor *fillColor = [NSColor redColor];
    NSColor *strokeColor = [fillColor shadowWithLevel:0.5];

    [fillColor setFill];
    [path fill];

    [strokeColor setStroke];
    [path stroke];

    return YES;
}];

redItem.image = redImage;
```

With respect to the token drawing stuff, take my info with a grain of salt because Apple's documentation on this stuff is pretty lacking, so everything I'm telling you is from personal struggles, cursing, and head-banging. Anyway, I'm sorry I couldn't bring you better news, but I guess, it is what it is. Good luck.